# How to give a new line in the entries from database to Excel

Tags: php, html, excel

The problem is with the last entry where $fetch==29. If I am not choosing this last option in my select page, the all other entries are not coming in next line. Is there a way to put \n somewhere else so that it doesn't matter which entries I select, it always gives a new line for every row.

Here's the code:

```
<?php

header("Content-type: text/csv; charset=UTF-8");
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=Mr Lucky - Selected Backcheck data.csv');
//connection

$dbhost = 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx';
$dbuser = 'xxxxx';
$dbpass = 'xxxxx';
$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
if (!$conn) {
    echo "Error connection";
}
//select db
$select_db = mysql_select_db('xxxxxxxxx_ssi', $conn);
if (!$select_db) {
    echo "Error to select database";
}

mysql_set_charset("utf8", $conn);

//Mysql query to get records from database
$user_query = mysql_query('SELECT details_ID, details_Interviewer, details_Name,        details_Phone, details_Address, details_City, details_Age, details_Gender, details_SEC,      details_Education, details_Occupation, details_time, details_TomMQ1, details_TomMQ4, details_L1M, details_favSalty, details_Q11Top, details_Q11Top2, details_ST1, details_ST2, details_ST3, details_ST4, details_ST5, details_Lays, details_KK, details_Bingo, details_Balaji, details_Q15, details_AdSeen FROM lucky44_data5 WHERE details_last=1');

//Code to show headings
$contents = "Password\t Interviewer code\t Name\t Phone\t Address\t City\t Age\t Gender\t SEC\t Education\t Occupation\t Time taken(mins)\t TOM MQ1(Macro)\t TOM Q4a (Salty)\t L1M Q7c\t Favorite salty Q5a\t Consideration top Box (Q11a)\t C Top 2 Box (Q11a)\t Brand I love\t Tastes better than other brands\t Have flavors you like\t Offers flavors which are different from others\t Have great advertising\t No. of statements endorsed for Lays\t No. of statements endorsed for KK\t No. of statements endorsed for Bingo\t No. of statements endorsed for Balaji\t Q15-Most Popular brand\t No. of seen ads (out of 5)\n";


//While loop to fetch the records

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($user_query)) {

    $fetch = $_POST['name1'];
    if ($fetch == 1) {
        $contents .= $row['details_ID'] . "\t";
    }

    $fetch = $_POST['name2'];
    if ($fetch == 2) {
        $contents .= $row['details_Interviewer'] . "\t";
    }

    $fetch = $_POST['name3'];
    if ($fetch == 3) {
        $contents .= $row['details_Name'] . "\t";
    }

    $fetch = $_POST['name4'];
    if ($fetch == 4) {
        $contents .= $row['details_Phone'] . "\t";
    }

    $fetch = $_POST['name5'];
    if ($fetch == 5) {
        $contents .= $row['details_Address'] . "\t";
    }

    $fetch = $_POST['name6'];
    if ($fetch == 6) {
        $contents .= $row['details_City'] . "\t";
    }

    $fetch = $_POST['name7'];
    if ($fetch == 7) {
        $contents .= $row['details_Age'] . "\t";
    }

    $fetch = $_POST['name8'];
    if ($fetch == 8) {
        $contents .= $row['details_Gender'] . "\t";
    }

    $fetch = $_POST['name9'];
    if ($fetch == 9) {
        $contents .= $row['details_SEC'] . "\t";
    }

    $fetch = $_POST['name10'];
    if ($fetch == 10) {
        $contents .= $row['details_Education'] . "\t";
    }

    $fetch = $_POST['name11'];
    if ($fetch == 11) {
        $contents .= $row['details_Occupation'] . "\t";
    }

    $fetch = $_POST['name12'];
    if ($fetch == 12) {
        $contents .= $row['details_time'] . "\t";
    }

    $fetch = $_POST['name13'];
    if ($fetch == 13) {
        $contents .= $row['details_TomMQ1'] . "\t";
    }

    $fetch = $_POST['name14'];
    if ($fetch == 14) {
        $contents .= $row['details_TomMQ4'] . "\t";
    }

    $fetch = $_POST['name15'];
    if ($fetch == 15) {
        $contents .= $row['details_L1M'] . "\t";
    }

    $fetch = $_POST['name16'];
    if ($fetch == 16) {
        $contents .= $row['details_favSalty'] . "\t";
    }

    $fetch = $_POST['name17'];
    if ($fetch == 17) {
        $contents .= $row['details_Q11Top'] . "\t";
    }

    $fetch = $_POST['name18'];
    if ($fetch == 18) {
        $contents .= $row['details_Q11Top2'] . "\t";
    }

    $fetch = $_POST['name19'];
    if ($fetch == 19) {
        $contents .= $row['details_ST1'] . "\t";
    }

    $fetch = $_POST['name20'];
    if ($fetch == 20) {
        $contents .= $row['details_ST2'] . "\t";
    }

    $fetch = $_POST['name21'];
    if ($fetch == 21) {
        $contents .= $row['details_ST3'] . "\t";
    }

    $fetch = $_POST['name22'];
    if ($fetch == 22) {
        $contents .= $row['details_ST4'] . "\t";
    }

    $fetch = $_POST['name23'];
    if ($fetch == 23) {
        $contents .= $row['details_ST5'] . "\t";
    }

    $fetch = $_POST['name24'];
    if ($fetch == 24) {
        $contents .= $row['details_Lays'] . "\t";
    }

    $fetch = $_POST['name25'];
    if ($fetch == 25) {
        $contents .= $row['details_KK'] . "\t";
    }

    $fetch = $_POST['name26'];
    if ($fetch == 26) {
        $contents .= $row['details_Bingo'] . "\t";
    }

    $fetch = $_POST['name27'];
    if ($fetch == 27) {
        $contents .= $row['details_Balaji'] . "\t";
    }

    $fetch = $_POST['name28'];
    if ($fetch == 28) {
        $contents .= $row['details_Q15'] . "\t";
    }

    $fetch = $_POST['name29'];
    if ($fetch == 29) {
        $contents .= $row['details_AdSeen'] . "\n";
    }
}

$contents_final = chr(255) . chr(254) . mb_convert_encoding($contents, "UTF-16LE", "UTF-8");

print $contents_final;
```

Comment: What is it about PHP's built-in [fputcsv()](http://www.php.net/function.fputcsv) function that makes it completely invisible in the documentation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try putting the values to array and then imploding them:

```
$tmpRow = array();
$tmpRow[] = $row['data_1'];
$tmpRow[] = $row['data_2'];
...
$tmpRow[] = $row['data_n'];

$contents .= implode("\t", $tmpRow) . "\n";
```

This way it doesn't matter how many columns you'll have. They'll all be joined by \t character and the line will have a \n at the end.

Comment: But what about headings?
See **$contents** in the code I showed.

Comment: How should it be working? In your example you just add all the headings to $contents and that's it. If that's what you need it will work your way.

Comment: Yeah. That's what I was saying. It's not working with the headings. I removed the headings, then it was working fine...

Comment: You might wanna go through your posted values and put the headings the same way before taking care of the data rows. Because now you have all  the possible headings, but only the data columns you actually need.

Comment: Just fill another $tmpArr with header values and the implode them and assign to $contents followed by \n character - exactly like you'd fill any other data row except this wouldn't happen inside the loop.

Comment: I'm glad you sorted this out and can move on. Hopefully many others will find the whole idea useful too

Answer (score 0):

```
$tmp = array();
$tmp[] = $row['data_1'];


// your code here


$tmp[] = $row['data_n'];

$contents .= implode("\t", $tmp) . "\n";
```